# Adding arguments to Flutter build pipeline test step in Azure DevOps with "vsts-flutter-tasks" extenstion

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, flutter-test

**Hi All,**

On my local machine I'm running the tests like below because of images in some of the screens. This works fine on local although I'm not sure if its the right approach.

```
flutter test --no-test-assets
```

I'm trying to create a flutter build pipeline in Azure DevOps. I use the azure extension for flutter from Aloïs Deniel.

https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks

**Below is the test step/task of the pipeline.**

```
- task: FlutterTest@0
  inputs:
    projectDirectory: $(flutterDirectory)
    testName: 'UnitTests'
    testPlainName: 'Unit Tests'
```

What I cant figure out is how to run the test step with the "--no-test-assets" argument.

Even if you guys can help on how to run my tests without the "--no-test-assets" argument, that would be even better.

**Below is how I load assets in pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter: 
  assets:
    - assets/
```

**Thanks again everyone who always assists.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters using **extraArgs**. Works the same for FlutterTest@0 and FlutterBuild@0.

```
- task: FlutterTest@0
  inputs:
    projectDirectory: $(flutterDirectory)
    testName: 'UnitTests'
    testPlainName: 'Unit Tests'
    extraArgs: '--no-test-assets'
```